# Xamarin Form: Is there a way to reduce the spacing on ToolBarItems

Tags: ios, xamarin, toolbar, toolbaritems

I am using the ToolBarItems on the navigation bar. On iOS, the toolbar items separated in quite a distance a apart. Can we bring them closer a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing between items is following the [Human Interface Guideline from Apple for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/). I recommend not violating the guidelines unless you have a very specific reason.

To answer your question:

You can use a custom renderer for [`UIToolbar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitoolbar) and or [`UINavigationbar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationbar) that places its subviews aka [`UIBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem) closer together.